# convert x and y coordinate from one android device to another independent of resolution

Tags: android

I have a canvas for painting in my application and saving all the coordinate while user drawing on it. the saved coordinates are then  transformed to another device and trying to plot the pixels.

like this;
(20,30),
(50,40)
..
..
..

Because of the different  screen size and resolution my drawing is incomplete and positions and plotted incorrectly

how can i map the coordinate to  other device which should be in exact location as that of the device  where i draw the actual image.

Comment: Hello, did we found out the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 8):

When you save the coordinates you need to get the device independent pixels from the drawing by dividing the coordinates by the screen density and when you draw it on a device you need to multiply your coordinates by the device density. For example:

```
float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
canvas.drawText(text, 
        xPos * density,
        yPos * density,
        mPaint);
```

Comment: can you please explain how to save the coordinate in the device where actual drawing is happening and how to  restore the point in any other device

Comment: That sounds like a broad question unrelated to what you asked. I'd suggest you save the drawing state on a server and have the other device retrieve it from the server. If you just want to connect two local devices then I'd suggest bluetooth. Either way this is no simple task to accomplish.

Comment: i know how to save the file, but i need the mathematical calculation during saving and restoring

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement density independent pixel(dp)

The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen.

The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple:
    px = dp * (dpi / 160).

So first determine your device dpi(dot per pixel).
So to move to (20, 30).
determine x = 20 * (dpi/160);
                             y = 30 * (dpi/160);

move to (x, y).

you can get dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density